# Convert List<DateTime> to String

Tags: flutter, dart

How to extract DateTime List to String and store it in two different Variables?

```
final  List <DateTime> datePicked = await DateRagePicker.showDatePicker(
   context: context,
   initialFirstDate: new DateTime.now(),
   initialLastDate: (new DateTime.now()).add(new Duration(days: 4)),
   firstDate: new DateTime(2018),
   lastDate: new DateTime(2025));

if (datePicked != null && datePicked.length == 2) {
   print(datePicked);
}
},
```

Output: 
2019-09-11 00:00:00.000,  2019-09-13 00:00:00.000

I want to store "2019-09-11 00:00:00.000" in a variable and

"2019-09-13 00:00:00.000" in a different variable.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I'm not at my PC at the moment, but try print(datePicked.) and see what intellisense brings up with the full stop at the end. I'll reply in about 30 minutes with my findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't much to say for this question if you are specifically looking for exactly two dates to convert **to string**s.

```dart
    String first = null;
    String second = null;
    if (datePicked != null && datePicked.length == 2) {
        first = datePicked[0].toString();
        second = datePicked[1].toString();
    }
```

More generically if you want to convert a List of Dates (of any length) to a List of Strings.

```dart
    List<String> stringsPicked = null;
    if (datePicked != null) {
        stringsPicked = datePicked.map((d) => d.toString()).toList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

to Convert a datetime to a String ou only need to use toString()..
like this

```
datePicked.toString(); // i'll name it MyDate
```

and if you want to split them

```
MyDate.split(",");
```